# Using "would" in questions to ask about past habits

Tags: grammar, past-habitual

I know the difference between *used to* and *would*. I've seen many examples of *used to* in questions, but I'm not sure if I've seen any for *would*. Are these questions correct to ask about someone's past habits, assuming the person who is being asked from is 60 years old.

> Would you smoke when you were younger?
>
> As a teenager, where would you hang out with your friends?

Is it possible to use *would* in this sense in questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with "would" is that it has lots of senses, such as forming conditional phrases or "future in the past". This makes your first example of a "garden path sentence".  Your interpretation of "would" has to change:

> Would you smoke...  {I think this is a conditional, I'm expecting an "if" clause like "if it was healthy"}
>
> Would you smoke when {hmm, the if clause is a when clause, perhaps "when no children are around"...}
>
> Would you smoke when you were younger {what?? I'm lost. I was younger, so that would can't have been a conditional clause. I've been led "up the garden path" meaning I've been tricked I have to go back re-interpret "would" as meaning "habit". Now I can understand, but it is confusing.}

Garden path sentences are not good English.

The second sentence is not a garden path sentence. The initial "as a teenager" sets a past time context. So there is no way that the "would" could be conditional, and the interpretation is straightforward.  So the second sentence is an example of good English.

Comment: Brilliant! If I place the when-clause at the beginning then, the question will be no longer confusing and that'll be OK. Am I right?

Comment: You mean "When you were younger, would you smoke?" Yes that is less likely to confuse.